# How to open product details in another page?

Tags: angular

I'm new to Angular, and i'm trying to make a simple ecommerce page, till now i've made a home page where i get from my API the products and show them with only data like title and price but the API also **returns lot of other data about each product**. So i was wondering which would be the best way to open on click a new page with all the details about that product.

Here is how i render my items

```
 <div *ngFor="let plu of filteredPlu" class="col mb-4">
      <figure class="card">
        <img
          [src]="
            plu.img
              ? 'data:image/jpg;base64,' + plu.img
              : 'assets/images/no_image.jpg'
          "
          class="img-fluid img-plu"
        />
        <figcaption class="card-body">
          <h6 class="card-title mb-0">
            <a href="#" appHref [routerLink]="['../item/' + plu.id]"> // ON CLICK WHICH SHOULD SHOW DETAILS
              {{ plu.desc ? plu.desc : "NO TITLE" }}
            </a>
          </h6>
          <small>{{ plu.estesa ? plu.estesa : "-" }}</small>
          <span class="price-wrap d-block">{{
            plu.prezzo | currency: "EUR"
          }}</span>
          <button
            class="btn btn-sm mr-2 btn-outline-dark mt-2"
            (click)="
              variantiModal
                ? openVarianti(variantiModal, plu)
                : addToCart(plu)
            "
          >
            Personalizza
          </button>
          <button
            class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-success mt-2"
            (click)="addToCart(plu)"
          >
            Aggiungi al carrello
          </button>
        </figcaption>
      </figure>
    </div>
```

So as you can see i have an anchor which redirects the user to /items/ component, the component where i should show the info about that item..

But i was wondering on how could i pass to /items/ the entire plu object, or i must make a new call to API to get single product info?

If it could be helpful my routing looks like this:

```
{
    path: 'negozio/:negozio',
    component: NegozioComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: ModuliComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'location',
        component: LocationComponent
      },
      {
        path: ':type',
        component: ProductsComponent, // products list is here
      },
      {
        path: 'item/:id',
        component: ItemComponent, // here i should show item details
      },
    ],
  },
```

And here is my service which returns items from API

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PluService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private adapter: PluAdapter) { }

  plu(idNegozio: number, piva: string, lang: string): Observable<Plu[]>{
    return this.http
    .get(`${Globals.API_URL}/plu/${piva}/${idNegozio}`, {params: { lang }})
    .pipe(map((data: any[]) => data.map(item => this.adapter.adapt(item))));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On product details page you need to get the ID of the product from URL param (you already have product id in param in URL path `path: 'item/:id'`).

And make a new GET request to fetch single product, that is the only correct way to achieve this, you can not pass a whole product object.

In your service add a new method which returns single product.

```
pluDetails(idNegozio: number, piva: string, lang: string, id: number): Observable<Plu[]>{
 return this.http
.get(`${Globals.API_URL}/plu/${piva}/${idNegozio}/${id}`, {params: { lang }})
...
}
```

On item/product details page get id param from URL and make a new call.

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private: service: PluService) {
  this.productId = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
}

productDetails() {
 const productDetails =  this.service.pluDetails(idNegozio, piva, this.productId)
}
```